# Instant search with Laravel Blade and Ajax,

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, laravel-blade

Here is my jquery code

I'm trying to run the code and Laravel blade is not recognizing the $results variable in the foreach statement.
I didnt add the code for the form neither the route. they work perfectly.

The main issue is to display the result from ajax in my blade file (The view)

```
// My Controller where i'm executing the search

<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Post;
use App\Tag;
use App\Lymstyle;
use App\Legende;
use App\Http\Requests;
use DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

class SearchController extends Controller
{
    public function getResults()
    {
        $query = Input::get('search');

        $results = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();

       ' return $results;'
    }
}
```

?>

```
// The Ajax Call, where i'm handling the post request and its reponse

var timer;

function keyUp()
{
    timer = setTimeout(function()
    {
        var keywords = $('#search').val();

        if(keywords.length > 0)
        {   
            var searchform  = $('.search').serializeArray();
            var url         = $('.search').attr('action');

            $.post(url, searchform, function(data){
                console.log(data);
                $('#search-results').html(data);
            });

        }

    }, 500);
}

function keyDown()
{   
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

<div id="search-results">
@foreach($results as $post)
     <h2>We found some...</h2>
@endforeach
</div>
```

I'm getting an error saying the $results variable in the view doesnt not exist

Comment: can you lag what which of this is blade file and controller part,,

Comment: Hi Jay, i have just edited the post with more details, please have a look

Comment: I think you are doing it wrong.. check my answer

Comment: save the headache use vue that whole code can be re-written in 6 lines. use the watch method to check for var changes on your input and just display a div if there are results. why re-render a view that will make things slower. you can also do this with jquery. and re-manipulate the dom element for the search-results div by replacing its content.

Answer (score 0):

You can `json_encode` the variable.

```
public function getResults()
  {
    $query = Input::get('search');
    $results = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>TRUE,'results'=>$results)); die;
  }
```

Jquery and Ajax:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#formid', function (e) 
{         
    e.preventDefault();
    var frm = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: frm.attr('action'),
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data)
            {
                var res = $.parseJSON(data);
                var result = res.results;
                 $('#search-results').html(result);
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think in your controller you wold need to return view instead of the results.

First put your following function in the separate blade file, lets say `search.blade.php`:

```
@foreach($results as $post)
     <h2>We found some...</h2>
@endforeach
```

Now, in your controller, return the rendered view instead of results.

```
public function getResults()
{

$query = Input::get('search');

$results = Post::where('title', 'LIKE', '%'.$query.'%')->get();

return view('search')->with('results',$results)->render();

}
```

Keep everything else same..

Comment: Undefined variable: results (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/limbolamagazine/resources/views/public/includes/search.blade.php) (View: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/limbolamagazine/resources/views/public/includes/search.blade.php)

This is what i'm getting

Comment: did you remove the `foreach` from main view ? you don't need it there

Comment: Thanks Jay. i finally decided to do a normal search operation (Not instant search anymore) and it's working perfectly. thanks for your help